# DLL is throwing access violation during multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

We ran in the problem that when we call a DLL in multithreading it crashes due to an access violation according to the supporter but sadly he didn't provide us with a workaround.

C# Error Message, Dump-Summary and Call Stack:

http://support.visualwebripper.com/Forum/TopicDisplay.aspx?si=7fa808b6-1b5e-4c70-b3cc-a3d8aa2fa4f5

Is there a workaround to still use our threads? Or do we have to resort to start each dll-call as its own process (which I'd rather not do)?

In principle each thread does nothing else than to start the dll with a different file.

Comment: If the software maker says "don't do that, it will crash", I think it's better to don't do it.

Comment: @manuell Sadly that was nowhere declared in the API documentation, we just got the information because of the ticket we created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much hope I would say. If the library is not designed to be multithreaded, then it will not work simply. You have especially little control when it is unmanaged code.

We had similar issues in the past, and we ended up creating an overcomplicated framework that would spin a separate process for every task and then manage the coordination between these processes.

Comment: Each thread does nothing more than execute a file (which contains the programm-parameters) and then saves the data in a MySQL-Database. I'm a bit worried about the access-handling of the database for different processes (never done that before). Otherwise the code for the thread could be made into an application that will be called in a proccess right?

Comment: @TestAccount, databases are safe to connect from multiple processes in general, unless someone deliberately disabled locking etc. Creating a separate application for every request sound like a good idea. It shouldn't be too bad if the communication between processes is so simple.